# What is causing the error "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have an onchange event that updates a form, and in the updating process it calls a function to calculate shipping. I'm not sure why, but I'm getting the following error when I try to call the function:

`Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function`

The function, `shipping`, looks like this:

```
function shipping( weight )
{
    var flat

    switch( weight )
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            flat = 32.00;
            break;

        case 4:
            flat = 18.50;
            break;

        case 5:
            flat = 15.80;
            break;

        case 6:
            flat = 14.00;
            break;

        case 7:
            flat = 12.71;
            break;

        case 8:
            flat = 11.75;
            break;

        case 9:
            flat = 11.00;
            break;

        case 10:
            flat = 10.40;
            break;

        case 11:
            flat = 9.91;
            break;

        case 12:
            flat = 9.50;
            break;

        case 13:
            flat = 9.15;
            break;

        case 14:
            flat = 8.86;
            break;

        case 15:
            flat = 8.86;
            break;

        case 16:
            flat = 8.38;
            break;

        case 17:
            flat = 8.18;
            break;

        case 18:
            flat = 8.00;
            break;

        case 19:
            flat = 7.84;
            break;

        case 20:
            flat = 7.70;
            break;

    } // switch

    var flat_fee = flat * weight;
    var mile_fee = distance * 0.90;

    var shipping_fee = flat_fee + mile_fee;
    simpleCart.shippingTest = shipping_fee;
    return shipping_fee;
} // shipping
```

I'm passing in `1` right now. The variable `distance` is coming from an ajax call that is completed before this function is run. That function looks like this:

```
function get_distance( zip )
{

    $.getJSON(
        'distance.php',
        { zip:zip },
        function(json)
        {
            distance = json 
        })

} // get_distance
```

I've checked to make sure the variable `distance` is set.

The console says the uncaught type error is happing at the line where I call `shipping(1)`. Any thoughts as to why that's happening?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you using `shipping` as a variable anywhere?  Sounds like the `function` shipping is getting overwritten by using it as a `variable` with a numeric value of `1`.

It's not in the code you posted (neither is the call to `shipping(1)` you mentioned).