# error : Number is not a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
var countRow = function(){
   var rowCount = $('#box_details tr').length();
   alert(rowCount);
 };
```

this code giving error like *number is not a function*, how to change this

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing the error "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332137/what-is-causing-the-error-uncaught-typeerror-number-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

**[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** does not have brackets

```
$('#box_details tr').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('#box_details tr').length();
```

use

```
$('#box_details tr').length;
```

`length` is a `property` not a `function` so use it like a `property` as shown above.

Your complete jquery code will look like as shown below :

```
var countRow = function(){
   var rowCount = $('#box_details tr').length;  //<---- correct here
   alert(rowCount);
};
```